# dominion online can't confirm email

Tags: technical-issues

I was trying to play dominion.games and actually paid for gold subscription. But I couldn't host any game because I couldn't confirm my email. I had tried multiple different email addresses and none of them received a single email from dominion.games the website. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a problem with email, not gaming.

Comment: @Frank it's not a problem with email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the issue was solved.
It's not a problem with email but the game website. I contacted the website staff using an interactive chatter on discordapp.com
https://discord.gg/MU8YJaR

They fixed the problem in one day.

But similar issues may occur again in future.